# List buttons being arranged in the grid without a gutter

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I've set up all the data for the page but my CSS isn't quite right and I can't seem to find a solution elsewhere to fix this. Using Knockout and Bootstrap 3 along with a couple of small plugins to make templating things easier. It's all default CSS code though.

I have a bunch of objects in my model which populate this page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRI9G.jpg

Code:

```
<div class="tab-pane panel-body" id="mainContentEmpireTechnology">
    <div class="panel-group" data-bind="foreach: technology.data">
        <div class="panel panel-default" data-bind="visible: isUnlocked() || $root.advancedTech()">
            <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-bind="attr: {'data-target': '#collapseEmpireView'+idName}">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <span data-bind="text: publicName"></span>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div data-bind="attr: {id: 'collapseEmpireView'+idName}" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body" data-bind="foreach: data">
                    <button class="btn col-md-3 col-sm-4" data-bind="css: cssStyle, visible: isUnlocked() || $root.advancedTech(), click: modalShow, text: publicName"></button>
                    <div data-bind="modal: {
                        visible: modal.visible,
                        header: { name: modal.headerTemplate, data: $data },
                        body: { name: modal.bodyTemplate, data: $data },
                        footer: { name: modal.footerTemplate }
                    }"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since this is all live generated and different sizes for each screen size I can't just throw it in a row, so is there another way to reproduce the margin between the buttons like in this but keeping the uniform button sizes (Also with a top/bottom margin the same size as the left/right)? https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5qOi.jpg

There's no additional stylesheet or js that's messing with the UI, just stuff which changes the button style to disabled/default/success.

Alternatively I could just make it "Modern/Metro" themed and get rid of the border radius from the buttons, but that seems like a bit of a cop out, and even that has margins to make sure they're easy to see.

Comment: rows don't produce margins, in fact the gutter in bootstrap is created by padding. When you put you put a btn class on a col-, it takes on the btn padding & then consumes the space because btn is after the col- css in the order. You can create a new set of css just for this situation using a re-named column grid and then set up margins - not padding. It would be like using the grid from before people used box-sizing:border-box or the old bootstrap 2 grid, which is named completely differently but it could be adapted. It would be a lot of work

Comment: however an easier idea is put, a span inside the button, then remove the btn styles on the btn and put them on the btn > span and then add some margin on that span, which you've changed to block

Comment: Thanks, Christina. I put the button in a span and that added the default gutter between the elements (As seen here: http://i.imgur.com/qD8NrwK.jpg). However, it doesn't include the top/bottom separation like there is for the panels. Ideally I would like it so that there's a small ~4px gap on all sides that doesn't interfere with the panel-body's padding, but this does help a bit. Is there no easy way to do a large grid of buttons like this in Bootstrap?

Comment: I'm guessing I could just have a custom .col-##.col-compressed css class that overwrites the padding to be 2px, but I don't know how to do it so it doesn't conflict with the parent's padding.

Comment: Actually, just adding a 2px padding class to the spans gives it enough gap between the buttons without looking out of place inside the panel. And it scales with having n elements in the grid as well. Thanks very much for at least pointing me in the right direction, even if I went slightly sideways from your suggestion :)

Comment: That's what I had in mind, 2px all around. Bootstrap is not all things for every scenario, so there is no way built in to do this, but you can roll your own